# Questions when proving a theorem with limits

Tags: calculus, limits

I encountered a question but forget how to prove it.

It goes like
$|\phi_n(x)-a|\leqq b$(where a and b are constants)

$\phi_n(x) \rightarrow \phi(x)$ (as $n$ goes to inifinity)

Is it true $|\phi(x)-a| \leqq b$

I think it is trivial but can not make it clear.

Here is my proof

For any $\varepsilon > 0$, for any $x$, there exists an $N$, for any $n>N$, we have $|\phi_n(x)-\phi(x)|<\varepsilon$
$|\phi(x)-a|=|\phi(x)-\phi_n(x)+\phi(x_n)-a|\leqq |\phi(x)-\phi_n(x)|+|\phi_n(x)-a|\leqq b+\varepsilon$

Really appreciate your help.

Comment: You have: for $x$ fixed it holds that $|\phi(x)-a| \leqq b+ \varepsilon$ for all (!) $ \varepsilon >0.$ Now let $ \varepsilon \to 0^+.$

Comment: Building on Fred's comment, to be more precise you can show that allowing $|\phi(x) - a| > b$ leads to a contradiction because you can construct some $\epsilon > 0$ such that $|\phi_n(x) - a| \leq b + \epsilon$ does not hold

Comment: You have $|\phi (x)-a|\le b+e$ for all $e>0$. This implies $|\phi (x)-a|\le b$. Because, if not, then $|\phi (x)-a|> b$, but then with $e=\frac {1}{2}(\,|\phi (x)-a|-b\,)>0$ we would have $b+2e=|\phi (x)-a|\le b+e$, implying $0<2e\le e$.

Comment: Can I just let $n \rightarrow \infty$ in the first expression and get the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true.

By continuity of the function $g(y)=|y-a|$, you have
$$
|\phi(x)-a|=|\lim_{n}\phi_n(x)-a|=\lim_{n}|\phi_n(x)-a|\le b
$$
where in the last inequality, you take the limit on both sides of $|\phi_n(x)-a|\le b$.

---

Your proof is also correct. Note that if for every $\epsilon>0$, $X\le Y+\epsilon$, then $X\le Y$.

Comment: By continuity what we get are all about $x$, but here is about $n$, so I am a little bit confused

Comment: @AndrewRen: it is the continuity of the $g$ that is used here: for every sequence $y_n$ with $y_n\to y$, one has $g(y_n)\to g(y)$ as $n\to\infty$. This is the sequence property of continuity.

Comment: So to be more precise, you choose a fixed $x$ randomly, and then $\phi_n(x)$ becomes a sequence. Then use the continuity of $g$, we get the answer.

Comment: Yes. I wouldn't use the term "randomly" though. One simply *fix* an $x$.